# Replace sequence of a charachter with another one

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I have an output from a network monitoring command and it looks like this:

```
                     391KB     7.48MB     7.86MB
```

Which have a lot of spaces first. Now I want to replace all spaces with `,`.
I tried `sed 's/ /,/g' input_file > output_file`, But result is not exactly what I expect:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,391KB,,,,,7.48MB,,,,,7.86MB
```

I even tried:

```
sed -r 's/(.*) /\1,/; s/ //g' file.txt > output.txt
```

But output was like below:

```
391KB7.48MB,7.86MB
```

How can I replace the sequence of spaces with one comma?
I think it's good to mention that I want to add this data to csv file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match a sequence of one or more spaces portably in Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) using either   `*` (space-space-star) or  `\{1,\}`. In Extended Regular Expression (ERE) you can use  `{1,}` or  `+`. The general name for these constructs is [Quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html).

```
$ echo '                     391KB     7.48MB     7.86MB' | sed 's/  */,/g'
,391KB,7.48MB,7.86MB

$ echo '                     391KB     7.48MB     7.86MB' | sed -r 's/ +/,/g'
,391KB,7.48MB,7.86MB
```

GNU sed allows you to use *escaped* `\+` in BRE (as well as `\?` for the 0-or-1 quantifier) - as does GNU grep.

You could also use `tr`, with the `-s` (`--squeeze-repeats`) flag:

```
$ echo '                     391KB     7.48MB     7.86MB' | tr -s ' ' ,
,391KB,7.48MB,7.86MB
```

However if you don't want an empty initial CSV field, consider using awk - since with the default field separator it will treat contiguous whitespace as a single delimiter, and ignore leading whitespace:

```
$ echo '                     391KB     7.48MB     7.86MB' | awk '{$1=$1} 1' OFS=,
391KB,7.48MB,7.86MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
echo '                     391KB     7.48MB     7.86MB' | sed -r 's/^ +//g;s/ +/,/g'
```

you will have

```
391KB,7.48MB,7.86MB
```

Or alternatively, if the separator is space and you can merge multiple spaces, you can use also the great [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) in this way

```
echo '                     391KB     7.48MB     7.86MB' | mlr --n2c --ifs ' ' -N --repifs cat
```

to have

```
391KB,7.48MB,7.86MB
```

Starting from a file

```
<input mlr --n2c --ifs ' ' -N --repifs cat >output.csv
```